# Hide unnecessary folders and files from project panel, in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When we create a project in Android Studio there will be many files and folders that not necessary to deal with them while coding.I want to hide it from the project panel and look clean.

- How can I hide selected folders and files from the project panel and show them only when I need it?

I want to hide selected folders below, and get them back when needed:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings. Then under Editor section, select File Types.

There's a section at the bottom to enter ignored files and folders. This may help you.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205824519-Is-there-a-way-to-hide-non-project-files-from-project-file-browser

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to mark the directory as Excluded:

[image]

and then disable the option to show them:

[image]

or... you can play around with [scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/settings-scopes.html#toolbar) in IntelliJ and select that instead of "Project".