How to show hidden .git folder in Android Studio?
I need to access the .git folder but I don't see it in Android studion project tree.
Could you please help me to show the hidden folder in Android Studio?
I've attached a screenshot of my current project view for reference. As you can see there is no .git folder shown there.

Thank you very much.

Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68039332/6330106. If .git is among the ignored patterns, remove it.

It worked, thank you!!!
